# Can I move another program's window to the front of focus?

Tags: java, windows

I am interacting with a third party application using it's API, and would like to move it to the front of focus (so that it is on top of all other open windows) when a user performs a certain action. While I can move my application up and down in the hierarchy pretty easily, there doesn't appear to be a way to interact with other windows. Is it possible to move another program's window to front with Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it in pure Java code, but you could using JNI. See [In Java Swing how do you get a Win32 window handle (hwnd) reference to a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386792/in-java-swing-how-do-you-get-a-win32-window-handle-hwnd-reference-to-a-window) for how to get a handle to the window. Then you could do something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545 to move it to the front.

Caveat: This is for windows only

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in pure Java and on certain OSes it's not even possible to cleanly get the other windows position (for example good luck doing that under OS X 10.4: OS X 10.4 does **not** have any documented mean to registered for other windows' events... There are "hacks", but they're really hackish, like requiring the user to turn on the *"Allow Assistive Device"* preferences, which requires the OS X admin passord).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to a very similar problem.
Until now I have found one - **very fragile!** - solution.
It works for my case, because my case involves running entire sessions using `java.awt.Robot` without user interaction, so it may - or may not - work for your case.

The solution is using `java.awt.Robot` to send the key strokes like `Alt+Tab` to bring the desired Window to the front.
This is fragile of course, due to multiple reasons:

- The Robot cannot know how often `Alt+Tab` needs to be send to get the desired window to front. The window is one in many. This solution only works if it's already known which window in terms of `Alt-Tab`-count it is.
- Depending on the OS, the required keystrokes might actually be something else.

In case the OS and the window sequence are known, i.e. the program can know upfront how many `Alt-Tab` keystrokes would be required, this could sometimes be a solution.

The following Java program demonstrates how to do this. If called without arguments, it generates exactly one `Alt+Tab` keystroke. If called with arguments, the program assumes the first argument is a number and it will generate as many `Alt+Tab` keystrokes as specified by that number.

You may want to play around a bit with the timing values given in `robot.delay()` and `robot.setAutoDelay()` in order to deliver the best experience on your machine. Hint: at least on Linux, `robot.setAutoDelay()` should certainly be less than the keyboard repeat delay, otherwise the OS would generate multiple `Alt-Tab` keystrokes in the system's event queue because of key repetition.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ALT;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class WindowSwitcher {
    public static void main(final String... args) throws AWTException {
        final int repeat = args.length != 0 ? parseInt(args[0]) : 1;
        final Robot robot = createRobot();
        robot.keyPress(VK_ALT);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            robot.keyPress(VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(VK_TAB);
            robot.delay(500);
        }
        robot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);
    }
    public static Robot createRobot() throws AWTException {
        final Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
        robot.setAutoDelay(10);
        return robot;
    }
}
```