# How to influence to position of a new process window in Java?

Tags: java, windows-8

I want to open an on-screen keyboard (osk or tabtip) when a Text field gets focus. This works but, in my current case, the popup keyboard always hides the Text field.

Is there any way to either influence the position of the window when it is started or to move it once it is opened?

I start the keyboard using ProcessBuilder.

```
cmd /C pathToExe
```

For my particular case it would be enough to fix it to the top-left of the screen.

(Using Java 1.6 and eclipse3 RCP, target Windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

This post might help you: [Can I move another program's window to the front of focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694365/can-i-move-another-programs-window-to-the-front-of-focus)

They are adjusting the window's Z-position (whether it is on top of other windows or not) but the Windows API they are accessing allows you to change X and Y position, too.