# java.awt.Robot: how to send mouse/keyboard events to a specific window? with cross-platform support?

Tags: java, window, cross-platform, handle, awtrobot

So from this question [In Java Swing how do you get a Win32 window handle (hwnd) reference to a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386792/in-java-swing-how-do-you-get-a-win32-window-handle-hwnd-reference-to-a-window) it appears that I can get the window32 handle .
would it be possible for java.awt.Robot to send mouse/keyboard events to that window handle?

sometimes when I am sending keys via Robot, if the window gets minimized, it will start typing into other background irrelevant windows that are open. I want to prevent this by allowing Robot to send keys and mouse events to that specific window of interest.

Would it be possible to achieve the same deal in Mac and Linux as well? be able to send Robot events to those  respective specific window handles?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem with Robot. As they have quoted in the other thread, its not possible with pure AWT/Swing. You have to get into sun's internal API or use native code. There is not getting around that problem.

It is exactly because of the problem that you have i.e. make it work across OS's is why Java has not exposed such a control.

It would be useful to know what you are using this for.