# Windows Forms Panel.Handle equivalent in Java swing

Tags: java, c#, c++, swing

I'm converting a C# windows forms application equivalent to a Java swing application and I'm stuck up at a position where I need to pass a window handle to C++ JNI layer.

In C++ layer, I've a function accepting `void*` pointer as window handle
ie

```
void SetWindowHandle(void* handle);
```

In C#, it is simply done as:

```
obj.SetWindowHandle(videoPanel.Handle);//videoPanel is System.Windows.Forms.Panel
```

In Java, I've created the UI with `JPanel` instead of `Windows.Forms.Panel`, but I've no idea how to get the handle for this `JPanel`.

Any idea, how it can be done? JFYI, this window handle is used in lower C++ layer as a handle for rendering video.

Comment: They use the handle from their JFrame

Comment: @Thomas Cud u giv some more details..specifically is there any direct property or method available to get handle of JPanel/JFrame?

Comment: I'm not really up to speed, but this will probably answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386792/in-java-swing-how-do-you-get-a-win32-window-handle-hwnd-reference-to-a-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue resolved by referring to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413895/1672927) mentioned by Thomas in comment section.

One point to be noted is that, to get this method works, you need to use `java.awt.Panel` instead of `javax.swing.JPanel` as this was the mistake I done and wasted one single day!